# Material dialog with multiple actions

Tags: material-design, actions, dialog

I am working on a material design dialog to create a new abence request. In this dialog all required information can be entered. After that the user can either directly request the absence or just save it for re-editing at a later point of time.

As Googles guidelines state that a dialog should have only two actions I wonder how I should present the „Cancel“, „Request“ and „Save“ actions.

It would be great if anyone can help me out with this and provide some recommendations.

Best regards,
Gerry

Answer (score 3):

Keep studying Google's Material guidelines :)  Their recommendations re: „Cancel“, „Request“ and „Save“ button placements would be in there. "Cancel" is generally the left-side button on a modal. "Save" is generally top-right in nav bar.

You should stick to the recommendation of two actions per modal. Providing a third action such as “Request” is not recommended as it navigates the user away from the dialog, leaving the dialog task unfinished.

> "Rather than adding a third action, an inline expansion can display
>   more information. If more extensive information is needed, provide it
>   prior to entering the dialog." 
>   **Source here**: https://material.io/design/components/dialogs.html#actions